# Why use Interface?

Tags: php, symfony

I looked [this tutorial](http://welcometothebundle.com/symfony2-rest-api-the-best-2013-way/#step-3a---interface-as-contract) to create a REST API, but I saw these practices from other bundles as FOSUser, FOSComment, etc ...

The tutorial explains (citing Symfony) it is better to outsource the logic of our controllers. I understand and I think it's great. But why create interfaces?

I do not know why it is safer to go through interfaces for our Entities and our Handlers.
I do not understand utility of interfaces to declare twice our methods.

I come from the frontend development, I am not entirely familiar with the backend environment, my question may seem stupid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interface is like contract OR blue print of your functionality.

For Ex.

> If you are creating class to render HTML element then it is necessary to set id and name of your html tag. So in this case you will create interface for that class and define method like setID and setName. So whenever someone will create any class to render HTML tag and implemented your interface then he must need to define setId and setName method in their class. In other word you can say that by help of interface you can set some definition of your object. Interface is very useful if you are creating architecture of any oop base application.

So, If some other people create class and want to hack(override) your functionality then it will through error if not exact method find in interface.

For this, First you have to go through OOPS concepts. Your most of concept about interface will be clear.